# How to add the delete,edit,save buttons to the each rows of browsed table using javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML page, there i am browsing and displaying the csv file.

I am failing with the below mentioned points, please help me with this.

1. I need to add the Edit, deleterow, save buttons to the each row of browsed file (edit button to edit the cells, delete button to delete the unwanted row, save button to save the edited cells).
2. adding the rows if required by clicking the 'addrow' button.

my goal is to make the table flexible in the displayed page itself

i have attached my code snippet also, please run and try it with choosing csv file and process.

I am facing issue while making it editable, please can anyone help me on this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
    <style>
        td, tr, th {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<script>
    function processFile() {
    var fileSize = 0;
    //get file
    var theFile = document.getElementById("myFile");
    
     var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
     //check if file is CSV
     if (regex.test(theFile.value.toLowerCase())) {
     //check if browser support FileReader
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
       //get table element
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;  
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);  
        var headerLine = "";
        //create html5 file reader object
        var myReader = new FileReader();
        // call filereader. onload function
        myReader.onload = function(e) {
            var content = myReader.result;
            //split csv file using "\n" for new line ( each row)
            var lines = content.split("\r");
            //loop all rows
            for (var count = 0; count < lines.length; count++) {
                //create a tr element
                var row = document.createElement("tr");
               
                //split each row content
                var rowContent = lines[count].split(",");
                //loop throw all columns of a row
                for (var i = 0; i < rowContent.length; i++) {
                   //create td element 
                    var cellElement = document.createElement("td");
                    if (count == 0) {
                        cellElement = document.createElement("th");
                    } else {
                        cellElement = document.createElement("td");
                    }
                    //add a row element as a node for table
                    var cellContent = document.createTextNode(rowContent[i]);
                    
                    cellElement.appendChild(cellContent);
                    
                    //append row child
                    row.appendChild(cellElement);
                    
                
                    
                }
                //append table contents
                myTable.appendChild(row);
                  
               
            }
            
            
        }
         //call file reader onload
          myReader.readAsText(theFile.files[0]);

        }
       
        else 
        {
              alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
        
    }
    else {
                alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
    }
    return false;
}
    
</script>

<body>
    <div class="form-inline">Select a file: 
        <input type="file" id="myFile">
        <button onclick='processFile()'>Process</button>
        <table id="myTable" contenteditable="true"></table>  
    </div>
   
</body>
```